# Bootstrap card animation when hover

Tags: php, css, hover, bootstrap-5, card

I have view where I show dynamically some cards that grow when hover. This is my css:

```
.card-deck .card {
    height:200px;
    width: 200px;
    
    transition: transform .1s;
}

.card-deck .card:hover {
    -ms-transform: scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.25); /* Safari 3-8 */
    transform: scale(1.25); 
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .card-deck .card {
        flex-basis: calc(50% - 30px);
        /* #{$grid-gutter-width} */
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .card-deck .card {
        flex-basis: calc(33.33% - 30px);
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .card-deck .card {
        flex-basis: calc(25% - 30px);
    }
}

.card-img-top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.card-title {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

And my home.blade.php:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card-deck">
            @forelse ($meetings as $meeting)
            @csrf
                <div class="card mb-3 bg-dark">
                    @if ($meeting['photoName'])
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ url($meeting['photoName']) }}" alt="Foto de la asignatura">
                    @else
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.arqhys.com/general/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/Roles-de-la-inform%C3%A1tica.jpg" alt="Foto de la asignatura">
                    @endif
                    <div class="card-body bg-dark">
                        <a href="{{ route('meeting.show', $meeting->id) }}" class="stretched-link text-white">{{ $meeting->title }}</a>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            @empty
                <h4> Nothing to show yet.</h4>
            @endforelse
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have 2 problems here that I can't solve:

1- When a card grows, it's over those that are in the previous row but under the card below that, so part of the card is hidden, how can I fix that?

2- The rows are made up of 4 cards but if the number of cards is not multiple of 4, I want the last row incomplete, not full filled by 1, 2 or 3 bigger cards. How can I do that?

Comment: For your first problem, you can use a higher value of z-index on hover.
And for the second problem, you have to replace the class="col" with class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6 ". By doing this you can see the 4 cards on large screens, 3 cards on medium screens and 2 cards on smaller screens.

Comment: I would suggest asking two separate questions and being specific to each you might get better results/

Answer (score 0):

`.card-deck` has been dropped

> **Breaking** Dropped `.card-deck` in favor of our grid. Wrap your cards in column classes and add a parent `.row-cols-*` container to recreate card decks (but with more control over responsive alignment).
>
> -- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/migration/#card

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row row-cols-4 g-2">
            @forelse ($meetings as $meeting)
            @csrf
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="card mb-3 bg-dark h-100">
```

Here is a working snippet with the 5th card wrapped:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row row-cols-4 g-2">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

````
<style>
.card{
border: 2px solid black;
}
</style>```
````

Comment: can you add some explanation instead of just code?